# Pandas use dictionary to convert multiple columns into percentages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, type-conversion

I have a data frame of 100s of participants completing different tests at 2 different time points. Here, I show only three such tests, namely AB, LC, MA. The values for these tests are raw values and each test has a different maximum value (for AB, the maximum is 150, for LC it is 12, and for MA it is 2000).

The data frame looks like this:

```
dict = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Visit": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "AB": [30, 40, 50, 20, 10, 10],
    "LC": [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
    "MA": [300, 900, 400, 400, 450, 350] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

   ID  Visit  AB  LC   MA
0   1      1  30   1  300
1   1      2  40   4  900
2   2      1  50   5  400
3   2      2  20   6  400
4   3      1  10   8  450
5   3      2  10   9  350
```

I want to compute a percentage score for every row based on each test's maximum value and append those scores into a new column with the suffix "_percent" (i.e., "AB_percent", "LC_percent", "MA_percent"). Is there a way to map percentages for columns based on different max values based on a dictionary and save these values into a new column with the suffix "_percent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'AB': 150 , 'LC': 12 , 'MA': 2000}

for exam_name, max_mark in my_dict.items():
    df[exam_name + '_percent'] = (df[exam_name] * 100 )/max_mark
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using this code:

```
df["AB_percent"] = df["AB"]/max(df["AB"])
```

Or more generally:

```
for col in ["AB", "LC", "MA"]:
    df[col + "_percent"] = df[col]/max(df[col])
```

This results in

```
   ID  Visit  AB  LC   MA  AB_percent  LC_percent  MA_percent
0   1      1  30   1  300         0.6    0.111111    0.333333
1   1      2  40   4  900         0.8    0.444444    1.000000
2   2      1  50   5  400         1.0    0.555556    0.444444
3   2      2  20   6  400         0.4    0.666667    0.444444
4   3      1  10   8  450         0.2    0.888889    0.500000
5   3      2  10   9  350         0.2    1.000000    0.388889
```

Comment: Thank you but the issue is that each variable has a different maximum value (for AB, the maximum is 150, for LC it is 12, and for MA it is 2000). How can I factor in a different max value for each column into this code?

Comment: You could do this by changing the value of `max(df["AB"])` to 150.
Or for the loop

    `for col, max in zip(["AB", "LC", "MA"],[150,12,2000]):
        df[col+ "_percent"] = df[col]/max`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
max_score = {
    "AB": 150,
    "LC": 10,
    "MA": 1000
}
df[["AB%", "LC%", "MA%"]] = df[["AB", "LC", "MA"]].div(max_score, axis=1).mul(100)
```

Comment: This should be the preferred approach, no need to loop. An alternative would be `df = df.join(df[list(max_score)].div(max_score, axis=1).mul(100).add_suffix('_percent'))`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a pandas-build-in functionality so I would just solve it with a straight forward smallish algorithm like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Visit": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "AB": [30, 40, 50, 20, 10, 10],
    "LC": [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
    "MA": [300, 900, 400, 400, 450, 350] 
}
# your dict with the max values
maxValues = {'AB': 150, 'LC': 12, 'MA': 2000}

# iterating through the max values
# and using the testname as name of the data-column
# to be used to calculate the percentage
for test in maxValues:
    newRowPercentages = []
    # iterating through the entries in the specific column
    for result in dict[test]:
        # calculating the percentage, styling is another topic
        # take a look at 'str.format()'
        percent = (result/maxValues[test]) * 100
        # appending the result to the array that is than...
        newRowPercentages.append(percent)
    # ...added as a new Column to your dict
    dict[test + '_percent'] = newRowPercentages

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

## OUTPUT:
   ID  Visit  AB  LC   MA  AB_percent  LC_percent  MA_percent
0   1      1  30   1  300   20.000000    8.333333        15.0
1   1      2  40   4  900   26.666667   33.333333        45.0
2   2      1  50   5  400   33.333333   41.666667        20.0
3   2      2  20   6  400   13.333333   50.000000        20.0
4   3      1  10   8  450    6.666667   66.666667        22.5
5   3      2  10   9  350    6.666667   75.000000        17.5
```

BTW if you are exporting such data to excel it becomes a breeze calculating and formating stuff like this :) but I do also like myself a goodl old "all in code" solution